# how create this kind of background

Tags: html, css, svg

I saw that many websites have similar backgrounds to this, and many designs on dribble have this backgrounds landing page. My question is how create this, and the photos on it is that SVG, IMG, or coded in CSS. [dribbledesign](https://dribbble.com/shots/5277096-Cloudshare-Web-and-Mobile-App-Service/attachments/1144856)
[another design](https://dribbble.com/shots/5276573-Ticketing-Software-Landing-Page/attachments/1144741)

Comment: have you tried using developer tools to see how they did it?

Comment: There's no way for us to answer these questions based on screenshots. As Julian mentioned, have you gone to these websites, right clicked on the page and used the "inspect element" feature to see how they created it?

Comment: good idea, i didnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we make them using Illustrator or Photoshop

They just attach some background image and make the navbar transparent and do the rest of the things

For samples: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=illustrator+designs&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIN802IN802&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzo_v1vcfdAhXbeX0KHVHOAAAQ_AUIDigB&biw=1517&bih=695

Comment: yes i understand that, but i am asking how to make that come live, how to make it on website

Comment: Just export the illustrator file as .png and make it as ur background in html

Answer (score 1):

Set background-image to selected element or the body using css and png image just like on the example

[image: cloudshare example]